# How to put tab marker of vaadin on the top?

Tags: vaadin14

How to have the blue underline to appear at the TOP of the text (Tab name) instead of the bottom?
[image]

I am using Vaadin 14

Answer (score 1):

Create file `frontend/styles/tab-theme.css` with content

```
:host::before,
 :host::after {
    top: 0;
}
```

Import it in your view with `@CssImport(value = "./styles/tab-theme.css", themeFor = "vaadin-tab")`, for example:

```
@Route
@CssImport(value = "./styles/tab-theme.css", themeFor = "vaadin-tab")
public class MainView extends VerticalLayout {

    public MainView() {
        Tabs tabs = new Tabs();
        tabs.add(new Tab("Tab1"));
        tabs.add(new Tab("Tab2"));
        tabs.add(new Tab("Tab3"));
        add(tabs);
    }

}
```

and that's it.

[image]

Tested with Vaadin 14.2.1